# xctrace sometimes hangs on "Waiting for device to boot"

Tags: ios, instruments

Sometimes when I run xctrace, e.g. `xcrun xctrace record --template Zombies --device <my udid> --launch -- 'MyApp'`, it just prints out "Waiting for device to boot" and then times out 30 seconds later. Does anyone know why this might be happening, or if there are any mitigations for it?

Comment: This is biting me too. Re - plugging the USB cable sometimes help , sometimes not. It also seems only happening on selected bundle identifiers, others seem to work flawlessly.